# Iframe content not displaying in Salesforce community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, iframe

I'm updating the iframe URL in a Lightning component that our Community uses with a new URL to point to a public microsite that the Marketing department created. However, the iframe content isn't displaying the microsite content:

[image]

I added the microsite URL to CPS Trusted Sites in Salesforce, but that didn't resolve it. Any idea why the iframe can't load the content?

Answer (score 1):

Check the [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header of the framed content to make sure that it is allowing you to embed it in an `<iframe>` first. If the content has the header set to `X-Frame-Options: DENY` then you won't be able to frame the content.

If you don't see that header value for the framed content, make sure you also check the "Allow site for frame-src" option in your [CSP Trusted Site Definition](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=5). Additionally, make sure you also check the community-specific CSP in the [Experience Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_security_csp.htm) as well.